# Soundcloud Metadata in Player

Tags: soundcloud

Just a question please - I have a Pro Soundcloud account, and a number of sounds which I embed on our site using the HTML5 Player.

I'd like to be able to display the date of the release in the player. I can see there is a metadata item for this, but I cannot seem to find any way to show it in the Player.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,

Toby.

Comment: Have you looked into the [Soundcloud API](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks)? There is a way to display the date that way.

Comment: Whereabouts ? I studied the API in order to build the site, and I can see how to upload and modify the date in there - but not how to display the date in a player?

Comment: Use the `release_day`, `release_month` and `release_year` properties of the API response.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the HTML5 player's design doesn't allow to show the release date.

You could retrieve the release dates for each of the tracks using the API with JavaScript to do that.